# Cannot push to my github private repository

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

As I'm learning git, I have set up a private repository on [GitHub](https://github.com). I have created ssh key and store it to my GitHub account and edited .ssh/config file on my local Linux machine:

```
    ## github
        Host github.com
        User git
        HostName github.com
        IdentityFile ~/.ssh/github.key
```

I can successfully connect to my GitHub account:

```
    $ ssh -T github
    Hi <UserName>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

I have initialized a git repository on my local machine, set up user and added a remote repository:

```
    $ git init
    $ git config user.name "UserName"
    $ git config user.email "UserEmail"
    $ git remote add origin ssh://github:<UserName?/<repositoryName>.git
```

I have created a `README.md` file, added it to git and commited it:

```
    $ git add README.md
    $ git commit -m "First commit."
```

Now everytime I try to push, I get this error:

```
    $ git push origin master

    ERROR: Repository not found.
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

Cloning the repository works, however that is the only thing I can do.

Why can't I push to my private repository? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get if you type `git remote -v`

Comment: I get the same error as with the `push` command.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try instead the [scp syntax](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php), to make sure your `~/.ssh/config` file is used:

```
git remote set-url origin github:<username>/<repo>
```

Then try and push again.

---

Git itself uses an OpenSSH version (at least the one packages with [Git for Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases))

```
> ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.5p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

As explained in "[Why doesn't the ssh command follow RFC on URI?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/75668/7490)", there is a difference between:

```
ssh://[user@]host.xz[:port]/path/to/repo.git
vs.
user@host.xz:/path/to/repo.git
```

Only the latter syntax `user@host.xz:` uses the [ssh config file](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/).

> When SSH was originally developed, it was developed as a more secure, drop-in replacement for the earlier RSH/rlogin suite of tools.

See "[History of the SSH protocol](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/#sec-History-of-the-SSH-protocol)".

[OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) (1999) predates [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) (finalized in [RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt), published in January 2005)

> If the host portion was allowed to be on the form `host:port`, this would create a potential ambiguity: does `jdoe@host.example.com:2222` refer to `~jdoe/2222` on `host.example.com` when connecting on the standard port, or does it refer to no file at all (or worse, `~jdoe`) on `host.example.com` when connecting over port 2222?

Comment: Worked like a charm. Accepted and upvoted. Could you explain why it does not work with `ssh://`?

Comment: @user44697 the first ssh://host:port/path follows an URI scheme, but ssh predates URI: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75672/7490