# Setup .ssh\config file and Intellij to push to gitlab

Tags: git, intellij-idea, ssh, gitlab

I'm running Windows 10, Intellij 2019.3.4, git for windows which come with git bash.

I'm hosting my code in gitlab.com

If I want to push my code to gitlab I run these commands in git bash:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add "D:\Projects\Project Name\SSH Keys\Project Name Key"
and I enter passphrase
```

Then I'm able to `git push -u origin master`

Now, I tried to add bypass this step by configuring `C:\Users\PC\.ssh\config`

```
Host gitlab
  Hostname gitlab.com
  User git
  IdentityFile "D:\Projects\Project Name\SSH Keys\Project Name Key"
```

and it is not working. I'm sure what I'm doing wrong here.

And I would like to be able to use intellij to push directly.

I tried giving my gitlab credentials it does not work

[image]

I generated a token from gitlab for intellij. I add it and it gives an error.

Nothing seems to work. I would really like to use intellij or atleast not have to add the private key and passphrase every time.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have modified your remote repo URL accordingly, from

```
git@gitlab.com:<me>/<myrepo>
```

To:

```
gitlab:<me>/<myrepo>
```

Second, test if your config works:

```
ssh -Tv gitlab
```

You should see a "Welcome to GitLab, `@username`!" message.

Finally, relaunch your IntelliJ and see if the issue persists.
This assumes that IntelliJ would suppose `.ssh/config`.
PyCharm, for instance, does not ([issue PY-21629](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-21629))

Comment: I don't understand your answer. can you elaborate? You said 'gitlab:<me>/<myrepo>' is this regarding to the config file?

Comment: @usertest No, that is the remote URL to use. the `gitlab:` part of the rmeote URL `gitlab:<me>/<myrepo>` is the part which will reference the key "gitlab" in your config file. That is because OpenSSH predates URI: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47368688/6309

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use GitHub integration in order to work with GitLab which is incorrect. Regrettably, there is no integration of GitLab in JetBrains IDE.

In your case, you need to go to VCS | Get From Version Control | Specify URL and folder where you want to store your project.

In order to make push work from IntelliJ you need:
 1. Make sure that Git works from Windows Command Prompt
 2. Go to Preferences | Version Control | Git and make sure that in "Executables" your path is set to Git\cmd\git.exe
 3. Try to push

Also please make sure that your SSH is configured as per:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Please let us know if it helps.